# display html tags in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor, google-code-prettify

I am opening the ckeditor with below content as default.

```
<textarea id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="30" cols="120"><p>We can use&nbsp;<strong>prettify&nbsp;</strong>to auto-format the Computer programming code at web page.</p>

<p><strong>How to use?</strong></p>

<p>Just add below line;</p>

<p><code class="prettyprint"><span style="line-height: 1.6em;">&lt;script src=&quot;https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;</span></code</p>

<p><span style="line-height: 1.6em;">Then, put the code line in below tab;</span></p>

<p><code class="prettyprint">&lt;code class=&quot;prettyprint&quot;&gt;...&lt;/code&gt;</code></p>

<p><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: monospace; font-size: medium; line-height: normal;">or,</span></p>

<p>Download the complete code files&nbsp;from&nbsp;<a href="https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/">https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/</a>(even can learn more about prettify)&nbsp;&nbsp;to your server and change above script tag line like below;</p>

<p><code class="prettyprint">&lt;script src=&quot;path/to/directory/run_prettify.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;</code><br />&nbsp;</p>
</textarea>
<script>CKEDITOR.replace( "editor1");</script>
```

But, in output HTML tag codes are missing. Output is below(under lines);

---

We can use prettify to auto-format the Computer programming code at web page.

How to use?

Just add below line;

Then, put the code line in below tab;

...

or,

Download the complete code files from https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/(even can learn more about prettify)  to your server and change above script tag line like below;

---

Expecting output:
[image: expected output]
Please help, where I am missing.

Comment: Did you do any additional settings? Which version of CKEditor are you using? How are you creating the editor?  if you can give some more information, maby we could help..

Comment: I am using 4.0.1.1 version. I am not using any additional settings. In ckeditor settings I disable few buttons and in 'Style' with 'Computer Code' option I add attribute 'class="prettyprint"'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like another similar problem in this question: [How to prevent CKEditor from stripping < and > (greater-than/less-than)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581139/how-to-prevent-ckeditor-from-stripping-and-greater-than-less-than)

The workaround is to use setData to set the value. Below is a test I got working in 4.1 samples.

```
<textarea id="editor1">
    <p>foo</p>
</textarea>
<script>
    var txt = '<p>We can use&nbsp;<strong>prettify&nbsp;</strong>to auto-format the Computer programming code at web page.</p><p><strong>How to use?</strong></p><p>Just add below line;</p><p><code class="prettyprint"><span style="line-height: 1.6em;">&lt;script src=&quot;https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;</span></code</p><p><span style="line-height: 1.6em;">Then, put the code line in below tab;</span></p><p><code class="prettyprint">&lt;code class=&quot;prettyprint&quot;&gt;...&lt;/code&gt;</code></p><p><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: monospace; font-size: medium; line-height: normal;">or,</span></p><p>Download the complete code files&nbsp;from&nbsp;<a href="https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/">https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/</a>(even can learn more about prettify)&nbsp;&nbsp;to your server and change above script tag line like below;</p><p><code class="prettyprint">&lt;script src=&quot;path/to/directory/run_prettify.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;</code><br />&nbsp;</p>'
    CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {
        ev.editor.setData(txt);
    });
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', { allowedContent: 'p' } );
</script>
```

Comment: Or better - encode the content of textarea correctly. All `&` -> `&amp;`, `<` -> `&lt;` and `>` -> `&gt;` will be enough. You won't need to use any workaround.

Comment: @Reinmar Thanks for the tip! I tried it and I failed :). If I use content like <p>Foo</p><p>&lt;&gt;Bar&lt;/p&gt;</p><p>Baz</p> it works just fine. But if I use <p>Foo</p><p>&lt;script&gt;Bar&lt;/script&gt;</p><p>Baz</p>, it fails (ACF set to `true` on both tests). So it looks like some security feature or filter is removing the script "tags" and that's why that method does not work here. Or I just did something wrong , which is very possible too :D

Comment: Oh yeah and OP, just remove the "allowedContent" rule from there or set it to whatever you need it to be, I had it for testing purposes.