# Prevent HTML tags from getting interpreted in CKEditor

Tags: java, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

In CKEditor (v4.5), suppose the user enters data such as:

```
<strong>Testing</strong>
```

into the editor and  the same is saved into the DB.

On reading and displaying the data, it is coming out to be:

**Testing**

How can this be prevented?

In other words, is it expected behaviour for the code to get converted like this?
If so, how can code be inserted?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Refer to this stackoverflow question


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581139/how-to-prevent-ckeditor-from-stripping-and-greater-than-less-than

Comment: This is a different scenario. The tags are not missing. Just that it shouldn't get interpreted.

Comment: tag your server side technology..

Comment: Any comments or solution?